# UITableViewCell separator refuse to disappear and NSTextAlignmentRight doesn't take effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using UITableView in my StoryBoard app.
Changing color work, direction doesn't work, separator line still appear.

```
    - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row320x44.png"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row320x44.png"]];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row320x44.png"]];
}
```

I tried in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableViewWallMessages.delegate = self;
    self.tableViewWallMessages.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableViewWallMessages.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Still nothing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //set the separator colour in the table (menu)
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

If that doesnt work then try adding the following in willDisplayCell

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Alternatively instead of using storyboard you could create it programatically

in the .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *myTableView;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong)UITableView *myTableView;
```

in the .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self;
    [myTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //set the separator colour in the table (menu)
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //set the number of rows in the table (menu) as 6
    int noRows = 6;
    return noRows;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//set the row height for the table (menu)
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    //Create a title label in the table (menu)
    UILabel *titleLabel;


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        /**TITLE LABEL SETUP**/
        //setup the title label
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 54.0, 77, 33)];
        titleLabel.tag = TITLE_TAG;


        //add the title label to the cell
    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];



}
else
{
    //recall the existing cell content if it has already been created
    titleLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TITLE_TAG];

}

//set the icon image as the image from the array


//set the menu item title from the array
titleLabel.text = @"some text";

//dont show the clicked cell as highlighted
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;




    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Code to execute when a cell is clicked on
}
```

Comment: Done and I still have the separator.

Comment: I tend to build all my tables programmatically as I find it works out better as storyboard doesn't get in the way and overide the things I ask it to do. There is a good tutorial here on storyboard tables including removing the separator line http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/   hopefully it will be of use to you

Comment: The guide actually work, thanks! But I've a UITableView in a UIViewController which take 50% of the screen and I don't think I can change the UIViewController to UITableViewController as I need to do another stuff in the 50% rest of the screen.

Comment: You can still use UIViewController just create it as a UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource using @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> Then you can declare a variable of UITableView *smallTableView and when you initialise it you can set it to be the size you want

Comment: I have edited my code above to include an example of how to build a UITableView within a UIViewController that leaves space to do other things on screen. You can move the position and size of the table by changing the CGRectMake

Answer (score 2):

Try setting Separator value "None" in Storyboard file.

[image]

Your code is correct, just make sure you have connected UITableView outlet with storyboard.